# MVCScaffoliding package throwing MethodInvocationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I've recently upgraded my VisualStudio 2010 installation with NuGet 2.0 and it seems that this breaks the MvcScaffolding package from Hanselman and Kirkland.  Whenever I attempt to build a new controller and views w/ repositories, I get a MethodInvocationError during scaffolding.  Specifically, System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException calling "Execute" with "5" arguements.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  According to the stack trace, this is happening at the NuGet.PackageExtensions.GetFiles() method.  Of course, the final statement in the stack dump is "You may need to upgrade to a newer version of MvcScaffolding", but I've determined that this is appended to the end of all the errors.  I'm currently using v1.0.7 of the MvcScaffolding package, which is the latest.  Anyone have any thoughts on why this is happening, and better yet, how to get around it?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem - I hope there is an answer to this!

Comment: I find if I use the NuGet console, I can create the controller OK. It's just the GUI integration that is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be still the case, also with VS2012 and the latest mvcscaffolding package. However as commented in other threads, running the commands in package manager console window does work. The [blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) by stevesanderson has syntax details